# Is it possible to filter prerouted packets in iptables?

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

I have following rules:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 1.2.3.4 -p udp -m udp --dport 6881 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.11.12.6
iptables -N RTORR
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.11.12.16 -p udp -m udp --sport 6881 -j RTORR
iptables -A RTORR -d 2.3.4.5 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A RTORR -j DROP
```

But filtering doesn't work. Looks like packets don't reach FILTER rule. Is it possible to filter prerouted packets?

Answer (score 1):

Let's analyze your rules.

```
-t nat -I PREROUTING -d 1.2.3.4 ... -j DNAT --to 10.11.12.16
```

Here, packets with **dest-address** of 1.2.3.4 are DNAT-ed. Which means that the **dest-address** will be replaced with 10.11.12.16

```
-I FORWARD -s 10.11.12.16 ... -j RTORR
```

This rule matches packets with **src-address** of 10.11.12.16. If you expect packets DNAT-ed by the first rule to match this rule... well, think again.

As you can see, the first rule changes the **dest-address**, while this rule tries to match with **src-address**.